# How do I store the upper case counterpart of a string?

Tags: expansion, strings

I have a string stored in a variable `\word`, and I want to store its upper case counterpart in another variable `\WORD`. If I try

```
 \def\WORD{\MakeUppercase{\word}}
 \show\WORD
```

then the message generated by `\show` is `\MakeUppercase {abc}`. Presumably I need to adjust the order of expansion in the first line. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, `\MakeUppercase` expands its argument before uppercasing it, so we can do the following.

```
\def\word{abcd}
\MakeUppercase{\gdef\noexpand\WORD{\word}}
```

`\noexpand` prevents the expansion of `\WORD`, but `\word` is expanded. Then `\MakeUppercase` uppercases the whole definition. The definition must be made global because `\MakeUppercase` works inside a group.

Comment: @Bruno - this doesn't seem to work. I get the error `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \def \WORD 
                      {abc}`

Comment: @Ian: right. I get where the problem is: `\MakeUppercase` tries to expand everything. Let me think a bit. A short solution is to replace `\MakeUppercase` by `\uppercase`, but it's not optimal.

Comment: @Ian: that's fixed, and we now don't need all those expandafters.

Comment: Very nice.  I taught myself a lot about `\expandafter` trying to figure out my own solution, only to find out that `\MakeUppercase` expands its own argument.  Putting the `\gdef` *inside* the `\MakeUppercase` had eluded me.

Comment: @Matthew: my first (wrong) answer involved some expandafters as well. I'm still wondering why the authors of `\MakeUppercase` enclosed the whole definition in `{...}`, rather than using the standard `\begingroup...\uppercase{\endgroup...}`.

Comment: It's amazing how tricky a seemingly simple task can turn out to be. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ian: I would say that this is still rather simpler than I feared. If you want more brutal code on uppercasing, see the answers on [how to get an expandable version of `\MakeUppercase`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/are-there-purely-expandable-variants-of-makeuppercase)