# Examples of tricky case-changing

Tags: textcase

The LaTeX team are looking to improve the implemenation of case-changing in LaTeX (`\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase`, plus potentially integrating the [`textcase`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package). To help with that, I'd like to ask for examples of 'tricky' case changing.

Each answer should have

- A short 'title' to explain what it shows
- The input you wanted to use
- What you *expected* to get as a result
- What you *actually* got

and for 'bonus points' how you got around the problem.

Good examples will probably include: using commands in text, accented characters, multiple languages, *etc.*

Comment: No specific examples, but encouragement to include `textcase`, so that math, `\ref`, and `\cite` aren't corrupted in the process.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's already on the list: the only trciky aspect is the optional argument to `\cite`

Answer (score 5):

## Storing case-changed text

Long ago, I posted a question asking how to [store the upper case counterpart of a string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13100/2417). In short, the result of

```
\def\word{abc}
\def\WORD{\MakeUppercase{\word}}
\show\WORD
```

is `\MakeUppercase{abc}`, whereas I would like `ABC`. The seemingly obvious solution

```
\edef\WORD{\MakeUppercase{\word}}
```

generates an error. @Bruno Le Floch solved this using

```
\def\word{abc}
\MakeUppercase{\gdef\noexpand\WORD{\word}}
```

which, in all honesty, I still don't understand!

Comment: `\MakeUppercase` expands its arguments and then uppercases it using `\uppercase` (plus a few protections for special input). `\MakeUppercase{\gdef\noexpand\WORD{\word}}` will expand `\word` and uppercase it, leaving `\WORD` unexpanded (`\noexpand`), so is equivalent to `\uppercase{\gdef\WORD{<contents of \word>}` (modulo the protection for special characters). Does this explain it?

Answer (score 4):

## Citation keys

Case changing gets applied to citation keys by the standard `\MakeUppercase` functions

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{a-key,
  author    = {Person One},
  title     = {A demo in lowercase},
  journal   = {Journal of Irreproducible Results},
  year      = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
A demo \cite{a-key}
\MakeUppercase{Some text \cite{a-key}}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which yields one missing citation:

[image]

This can be handled using the `textcase` package

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{a-key,
  author    = {Person One},
  title     = {A demo in lowercase},
  journal   = {Journal of Irreproducible Results},
  year      = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
A demo \cite{a-key}
\MakeUppercase{Some text \cite{a-key}}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which then gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Math mode

Math mode material should not be case changed, but

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{Some text $y = mx + c$}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

which can be fixed using `textcase`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{Some text $y = mx + c$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Headers

Headers of chapters are set using `\MakeUppercase` by default (in [`book`](//www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and [`report`](//www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co)). Undefined references in chapter titles end up with warnings in the `.log` also showing in all-caps:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\chapter{A chapter before Chapter~\ref{ch:two}}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Here's the `.log` showing an uppercase warning with the setting of every `\chapter`-related mark (even pages):

```
Chapter 1.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `ch:two' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.

[1


{c:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LATEX WARNING: REFERENCE `CH:TWO' ON PAGE 1 UNDEFINED on input line 10.

[2] [3]

LATEX WARNING: REFERENCE `CH:TWO' ON PAGE 1 UNDEFINED on input line 10.

[4] [5]

LATEX WARNING: REFERENCE `CH:TWO' ON PAGE 1 UNDEFINED on input line 10.

[6] [7]

LATEX WARNING: REFERENCE `CH:TWO' ON PAGE 1 UNDEFINED on input line 10.

[8] [9]

LATEX WARNING: REFERENCE `CH:TWO' ON PAGE 1 UNDEFINED on input line 10.

[10]
Chapter 2.
[11

] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19] [20] (./latex_stuff.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
```

Answer (score 2):

### Expanding the `nonchangecase` list of `textcase` for uppercase captions/headings

Maybe the new version of `\MakeUppercase` can expand the `\@nonchangecase` list of `textcase` to a wider range of commands?

For instance, suppose that a template requires uppercase section heads and uppercase captions. You'd like end-users to be able to use `\eqref` in captions and `\footnote` in headings without having to call `\NoCaseChange`.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcase}  

\usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1} #2}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{uppercase}{#1 #2 {\MakeTextUppercase #3}}
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=uppercase, labelfont=bf, format=uppercase}

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\raggedright}{\thesection .}{0.5em}{\MakeTextUppercase}

%% Patch textcase to include \footnote and \eqref. 
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}  
    \patchcmd{\@uclcnotmath}{\@nonchangecase\ref}{\@nonchangecase\ref\@nonchangecase\footnote}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\@uclcnotmath}{\@nonchangecase\ref}{\@nonchangecase\ref\@nonchangecase\eqref}{}{} 

%% And stop \footnote from causing problems with \sectionmark
    \robustify{\footnote}      
    \patchcmd{\section}{\sectionmark}{\let\footnote\@gobble\sectionmark}{}{} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section heading with a footnote\footnote{Footnote that does not need \texttt{\textbackslash NoCaseChange}.}}
Some text (see Fig.~\ref{fig:1}) and an equation
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:tag}
A = B
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption with math, eqn.~\eqref{eqn:tag}: $z = (r,\phi)$ \cite{latexdps}\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{latexdps} 
  Leslie Lamport. \textit{\LaTeX{}: a document preparation system}. Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]