# Set chapter header to small caps and bold in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script

This is my first question here, I did search but uhmm haven't found the answer.
I have a document that must follow the next rules:
The chapter header in uppercase and bold and arial 13 pt;
section header in lowercase and arial 13 pt;
subsection header in lowercase and slanted font and arial 13 pt;
and finally the main font for the document is arial 12 pt.

Following [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25150/using-makeuppercase-in-startsection) Along with the scrbook guide (p. 55) I can almost get it, except for the chapter header that I am not sure how to make at the same time bold and in small caps.

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish]{scrbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\increase\rmfamily\scshape}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\increase}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\increase\rmfamily\slshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Un título bastante largo para probar}
Algo de texto ¿Por qué no?
\section{Un título bastante largo para probar}
Algo de texto ¿Por qué no?
\subsection{Un título un poquitillo más largo}
Algo de texto ¿Por qué no?, así es.
\end{document}
```

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You write you "can almost get it", but your description of the sought formatting doesn't match your example (which, BTW, I couldn't test because I lack the `uarial` package and the `\increase` command). That said, the following KOMA-Script font settings should do what you want:

```
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{13}{15.5}\selectfont\scshape}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\fontsize{13}{15.5}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\slshape\fontsize{13}{15.5}\selectfont}
```

If you need capitals instead of small capitals for `\chapter` (or if `uarial` doesn't provide bold, sans-serif, small capitals), replace `\scshape` with `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: Well, here it says how to install and use uarial [link] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957/how-to-set-font-to-arial-throughout-the-entire-document).

What I think the increase command does is to increment 1 pt the normal font (which is arial 12pt).  Maybe it is to some other package.
\MakeUppercase does the trick. 

Thanks.

Comment: @murpholinox You're welcome -- and don't forget to upvote and accept my answer. :-)