# Uppercase chapter with KOMA-script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, capitalization

It has already been mentioned that it could be tricky to get uppercase letters in chapter for `scrbook`. However, the solution in [Using \MakeUppercase in \@startsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25150/using-makeuppercase-in-startsection) works for `scrreprt`.

The solution used in `tudscr` adds a custom command to make the text uppercase, but then chapter has to be redefined.

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand*\mymakeuppercase[1]{%
        \ifdin{\begingroup\MakeTextUppercase{#1}\endgroup}{#1}%
    }
\makeatother
```

Any other alternative, that would be applicable to all koma scripts?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

% Fix \MakeUppercase
\usepackage{makerobust}
\makeatletter
\MakeRobustCommand\@hangfrom
\newcommand*{\ModMakeUppercase}{%
    \MakeRobustCommand\@svsec
    \MakeUppercase
}
\makeatother

\addtokomafont{part}{\MakeUppercase}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase} % <- doesn't work
\addtokomafont{section}{\ModMakeUppercase}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\ModMakeUppercase}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE which can be compiled.

Comment: Could be a possible bug in 3.16 that will be fixed with the next release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

Since **KOMA-Script version 3.19** the recommended way is redefining `\sectionlinesformat`, `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
}
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \MakeUppercase{#2#3}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3\MakeUppercase{#4}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{Test}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

There is a problem in KOMA-Script Version 3.16 (and 3.15). As a workaround:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

% Fix \MakeUppercase
\usepackage{makerobust}
\makeatletter
\MakeRobustCommand\@hangfrom
\newcommand*{\ModMakeUppercase}{%
    \MakeRobustCommand\@svsec
    \MakeUppercase
}
\makeatother

\addtokomafont{part}{\MakeUppercase}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase}
\addtokomafont{section}{\ModMakeUppercase}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\ModMakeUppercase}

% workaround for version 3.15 and 3.16
\deftocheading{toc}{\chapter*{#1}}% <- added
\deftocheading{lof}{\chapter*{#1}}% <- added
\deftocheading{lot}{\chapter*{#1}}% <- added

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{Test}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know this problem will be fixed with the next release (3.17). Additionally `\addtokomafont{section}{\MakeUppercase}` and `\addtokomafont{subsection}{\MakeUppercase}` will also work.

Comment: What if, in addition to the chapters, I require that the sections also appear in capital letters?

Comment: @Aradnix You have to redefine `\sectionlinesformat`  and maybe `\secrioncatchphraseformat` as shown in the first example. If this does not help then ask a new question with a MWE showing your issue.