# EBGaramond lining numbers for headings in KOMAScript

Tags: fonts, koma-script, ebgaramond

I'm using [KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en) with `pdflatex` (might want to switch to `lualatex` eventually) to typeset my thesis and want to use EBGaramond as a font. To this end I am loading the [`ebgaramond-maths`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond) package, which in turn loads the [`ebgaramond`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond) package. The latter offers various styles of the font, including different number figures. I really like the default old-style figures in the body text, but I don't think they lend themselves too well for headings. So I want to change the number style *only in the headings and TOC*. The [`ebgaramond` `README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ebgaramond/README) gives us the following ways to choose a style:

> To use, add `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` to the preamble of your document. Options include:
>
> - `oldstyle`,`osf`    old-style figures
> - `lining`,`nf`,`lf`    lining figures
>
> […]
>   Commands `\oldstylenums{...}` and `\liningnums{...}` are defined to allow for local use of old-style figures or liningfigures, respectively.

Changing the style globally is not an option, so we're left with using `\liningnums{}`. **How do I use it correctly with KOMA-Script?**

I've tried various methods, to no success:

1. The first intuition would be to use `\addtokomafont`

```latex
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\liningnums{}}
```

(`\rmfamily` because I want serif style headings). This works for `\chapter`s but not `\section`s in the MWE, but it doesn't work in my actual document and throws

```
! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
```

I don't know what's messing with it here, but it's also [discouraged by the KOMA-Script documentation (section 3.6)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf):

> Sometimes, although this is not recommended, the font setting of an element is used for settings that are not actually related to the font. […]
>   However, you should not take these commands as legitimizing the insertion of arbitrary commands in an element’s font setting. To do so can lead quickly to errors (see section 21.5, page 476).

2. According to [this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234801/uppercase-chapter-with-koma-script), one should change `\chapterlinesformat` and the like

```
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{\liningnums{#2#3}}
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[3]{\liningnums{#2#3}}
% ...
```

But this doesn't work either. When I only set `\chapterlinesformat` it works for `\chapter`s but messes with the font styles. In the TOC, the `\chapter` font is set to sans-serif Computer Modern, while `\section` and `\subsection` is left at serif Garamond. In the main document however it's exactly opposite: `\chapter` has the correct lining figures and is correctly typeset in Garamond, but now the `\section` and `\subsection` are in sans-serif Computer Modern. If dare to add the `sectionlinesformat` line, I get the error

```
! You can't use `\glueexpr' in horizontal mode.
```

**How do I correctly tell KOMA-Script to use `liningnums{}` for headings in the body text and TOC?** No hacks please, I want a clean KOMA-Scriptonic solution.

---

Minimal (not)Working Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
    %\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\liningnums}
    \renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{\liningnums{#2#3}}
    %\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[3]{\liningnums{#2#3}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can switch the font family to the lining font:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\fontfamily{EBGaramond-LF}\selectfont}
\AfterTOCHead{\renewcommand\rmdefault{EBGaramond-LF}\normalfont} %for the toc
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{88}
    \chapter{Chapter 89}
    0123456789
    \section{Section 89}
    \subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect and even cleaner than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, the table of contents has the chapters now typeset in Computer Modern Sans and the sections in Garmond but with old style figures...

Comment: KOMA has suitable command to setup the fonts in the table of contents in a similar way.

Comment: I'm sorry, somehow the `\selectfont` got lost. The font choice works in the TOC as well, but sections still have old-style figures. When I try to `\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\fontfamily{EBGaramond-LF}\selectfont}`, pdflatex tells me "font of element 'sectionenrty' can't be extended" and the KOMA-Script manual says "sectionentry" is only available in `scrartcl` (p63)

Comment: I added an edit for the toc. One could also redefine the single entries, but simply switching \normalfont is easier.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much1

Comment: Thank you! EBGaramond's \liningnums{} failure to work in section headers has been a long headache. I presume it's an expansion problem but I couldn't find the solution. This solves it neatly at a local level. Wherever I need lining numbers in a header as part of the header text I simply insert {\fontfamily{EBGaramond-LF}\selectfont 1.0} into the header text (1.0 or whatever number(s) I need to use). Latex then properly italicizes and all-caps it in the header, leaves it normal font in the TOC and bolded or however I format it in the actual header text on the page.