# Uppercase section titles and TOC for scrreport document class

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, koma-script, uppercase

I'm trying to combine [Uppercase, italics and hyperlinks in toc of scrartcl without using tocstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299473/uppercase-italics-and-hyperlinks-in-toc-of-scrartcl-without-using-tocstyle) and [Uppercase chapter with KOMA-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234801/uppercase-chapter-with-koma-script):

```
\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsubsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
```

However, the TOC links do not lead anywhere. Any ideas how to fix this?

I tried to replace

```
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
```

with

```
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}%
```

but I get the `\MakeUppercase ...ppercaseUnsupportedInPdfStrings` error. The document is produced with pandoc, so I can only add some latex snippets.

I'm completely new to LaTeX, so I would really appreciate not only a solution, but also any hints on how to debug such problems myself.

UPD: below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
% Run "xelatex example.tex" (twice) to compile to pdf
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}

\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsubsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3\MakeUppercase{#4}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% This command breaks TOC hyperlinks
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

Even if I add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen}` the code still works for me, but I use the uptodate KOMA-Script version 3.31 (2020/07/22). In previous versions there was a problem with `hyperref` and unnumbered sections, see [Bekannte Probleme und Änderungen in KOMA-Script 3.30](https://komascript.de/release3.30) (German). So maybe you have to update.

```latex
% Run "xelatex example.tex" (twice) to compile to pdf
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2020/07/22]% version 3.31 or newer
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}

\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsubsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3\MakeUppercase{#4}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% This command breaks TOC hyperlinks
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

\begin{document}
\KOMAScriptVersion% added to show the KOMA-Script version in the document
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

### [image]

**Original answer**:

To long for a comment:

The following example works for me.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsectiontocdepth}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip#2#3\MakeUppercase{#4}%
}

\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your example also works for me. However, default pandoc template doesn't. I spent two hours stripping down the default template and found the culprit:

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

So I guess there is some conflict between MakeUppercase and this line. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. Maybe you can add a minimal working example to your question which shows the problem. Or you ask a new question including a MWE (minimal working example).

Comment: I used your example document as a base and added the line that breaks TOC hyperlinks. The resulting MWE is added to my question.

Comment: See my updated answer. Which KOMA-Script version do you use?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it! I used the default koma-script package that came with MacTeX 2020, I believe it was 3.29. The problem went away after I did `sudo tlmgr update --self` and then `sudo tlmgr update koma-script`. I would have never figured that out myself...  You rock!