# Section title disappears using tikz in xelatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, xetex

I am writing my thesis using xelatex.  I use TikZ package to make figures.  Although when I check my pdf it makes figures correctly, but it gives following error

> "! Missing { inserted."

And section title disappears everywhere, although subsection titles are showing. For the clarity, I have added the main file of code of my thesis. If I remove tikz package then code runs fine, except that the figures are not generated. The problem is only with the tikz package, I have checked it several times.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,bibliography=totoc, fleqn,enabledeprecatedfontcommands]{scrbook}

 \usepackage{fontspec}

 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

 \usepackage{scrpage2}

\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ofoot[]{}
\pagestyle{scrplain}
\renewcommand*{\pnumfont}{\normalfont \sffamily\fontsize{10}{10}\bfseries}

\setlength{\parskip}{11pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in} % paragraph left indentation

\usepackage{indentfirst} % to set indent for first paragraph

\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage[a4paper, 
left=12.5mm,right=12.5mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=19.5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[small,sf,bf]{titlesec}
\setmainfont[]{Book Antiqua} 

\setsansfont{Candara}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\fontsize{18}{11} \flushright\sffamily \bfseries}{\normalfont 
\fontsize{27}{11}\sffamily \textit \chaptername \thechapter}{0pt}
{\fontsize{27}{11}}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont  \sffamily\bfseries \fontsize{13}{11}\MakeUppercase}
{\sffamily\thesection}{0.2em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
 {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{11}\sffamily\bfseries}{\sffamily\thesubsection}
 {0.2em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{11}\sffamily\bfseries\itshape}
{\sffamily\thesubsection}{0.2em}{}

 \titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{44pt}
 \titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{22pt}{-11pt}
 \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{11pt}{-11pt}
 \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{11pt}{-11pt}

  \usepackage{mdwlist}

  \usepackage[labelfont=bf,font={normalsize,sf}]{caption}
  \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colon}{ : }
  \captionsetup{labelsep=colon}
   \usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
   \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \usepackage{mathptmx}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{algorithm2e}



   \newtheorem{theorem}{\sffamily\textbf{Theorem}\rmfamily}[chapter]
   \newtheorem{proposition}{\sffamily\textbf{Proposition}\rmfamily}[chapter]

    \newtheorem{definition}{\sffamily\textbf{Definition}\rmfamily}[chapter]

    \newtheorem{pro}{\sffamily\textbf{Procedure}\rmfamily}[chapter]

    \newtheorem{example}{\sffamily\textbf{Example}\rmfamily}[chapter]

    \newtheorem{corollary}{\sffamily\textbf{Corollary}\rmfamily}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{lemma}{\sffamily\textbf{Lemma}\rmfamily}[chapter]
   \newtheorem{algo}{\sffamily\textbf{Algorithm}\rmfamily}[chapter]
   \renewenvironment{proof}{\hspace{-35pt}\sffamily 
   \textbf{Proof:}\rmfamily}{}
    \setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}
    \usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

    \usepackage[square]{natbib}
      \renewcommand\bibname{References} % to change name 'Bibliography' to 
   ''References
    \setlength{\bibsep}{0pt} % to force space between references to zero

      \setlength{\textfloatsep}{33pt} %distance between floats on the top or 
     the bottom and the text;
     \setlength{\floatsep}{33pt} %distance between two floats;
   \setlength{\textfloatsep}{33pt} %distance between floats inserted inside 
   the page text (using h) and the text proper
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{11pt} % set space between caption and 
   figure float
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{11pt} % set space between caption and 
   table float


  \usepackage[smaller,style=long3colheader,acronyms,nopostdot,nonumberlist]
 {glossaries}
   \renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}} % make name of the glossary 
      item in normal (bold otherwise) 
       \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\sf \textmd{#1}\hspace{30pt}}
       \renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[2]{\textsf{#1}} % for changing font of 
   acronyms
    \renewcommand*{\firstacronymfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
     \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}
      \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
       \vspace{11pt} \sf \itshape \fontsize{10}{100} Symbol & \sf \itshape 
      \fontsize{10}{100} Description \\\endhead}



         \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{acronym}
     \renewcommand*{\entryname}{Abbreviation}
    \renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Full Form}
      \renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{}
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.9\linewidth}
   \makeglossaries
 \input{listofsymbols/listofsymbols} % .tex file containing glossary entries 
 for symbols
    \input{listofabbreviations/listofabbreviations} % .tex file containing 
    acronym entries for abbriviations

     \usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}
      \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\fontsize{11}{10}\sffamily\bfseries}
      \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont \fontsize{10}
     {10}\sffamily}
     \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
         \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
      \renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{57pt}
       \renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0pt}
         \renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{24pt}
        \renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{26pt}
        \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontsize{10}{10} \sffamily}
        \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont \fontsize{10}{11} 
        \sffamily\itshape}
          \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\normalfont \fontsize{10}{11} 
     \sffamily\itshape}
       \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\normalfont \fontsize{10}{10} \sffamily}
      \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\normalfont \fontsize{10}{10} \sffamily}
  \renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
    \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalfont \fontsize{14}{11} 
   \sffamily\bfseries}
      \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\normalfont \fontsize{14}{11} 
    \sffamily\bfseries}
   \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\normalfont \fontsize{14}{11} 
    \sffamily\bfseries}
      \cftsetrmarg{60pt}



    \makeatletter
  \newcommand*\updatechaptername{%
    \addtocontents{toc}
      {\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchappresnum{Annexure}}
       }
    \makeatother



        \makeatletter
      \newcommand*\updatechapnumafter{%
    \addtocontents{toc}
    {\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchapnumwidth{67pt}}
     }
      \makeatother
    \begin{document}
      \include{titlepage/titlepage}
   \frontmatter
       \include{declaration/declaration}
    \include{certificate/certificate}
     \include{abstract/abstract}
    \include{ack/ack}
       \clearpage
       \tableofcontents
       \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \hfill \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} 
    \textit{page} \par}
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} 
      \textit{Abstract} \protect \hfill \protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}
    {10}\textit{i}\par}
     \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} 
       \textit{Acknowledgements} \protect \hfill \protect \sffamily 
     \fontsize{10}{10}\textit{iii}\par}
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} 
     \textit{Contents} \protect \hfill \protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}
   {10}\textit{v}\par}
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} \textit{List 
     of Figures} \protect \hfill \protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}
    {10}\textit{vii}\par}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} \textit{List of 
     Tables} \protect \hfill \protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}
     {10}\textit{viii}\par}
          \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} 
     \textit{List of Symbols} \protect \hfill \protect \sffamily 
  \fontsize{10}{10}\textit{ix}\par}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}{10} \textit{List of 
     Abbreviations} \protect \hfill \protect \sffamily \fontsize{10}
      {10}\textit{x}\par}

     \renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{10pt}
     \renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{37pt}
  \listoffigures


    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect \sffamily\itshape \fontsize{10}{10} Figures 
      \protect\hspace{10pt} Title \protect\hfill\mbox{page}\par}

      \renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{10pt}
     \renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{37pt}
     \listoftables
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect \sffamily\itshape \fontsize{10}{10} Figures 
   \protect\hspace{10pt} Title \protect\hfill\mbox{page}\par}

    \printglossary[title=List of Symbols]
   \printglossary[type=acronym, title=List of Abbreviations]



     \protect\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\mainmatter
  \include{chapter1/chapter1}
   \include{chapter2/chapter2}
     \include{chapter3/chapter3}
 \include{chapter4/chapter4}
  \include{chapter5/chapter5}
    \include{chapter6/chapter6}


   \protect\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Annexure }
 \appendix
 \updatechapnumafter
    \updatechaptername
   \chapter{aa}


     \backmatter


   \bibliographystyle{iitjphd}
     \bibliography{bibliography/references}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: why do you think it is related to tikz? Given the (minimal) information you have provided  it would seem to be an error in a section heading, most likely use of a fragile command without `\protect`

Comment: It is certainly related tikz. If I remove tikz package sections are working perfectly fine, although obviously figures will not be generated.

Comment: you need to give some hint prefereably a small complete document that shows the problem.  There is absolutely nothing in the question that relates to tikz or section headings. So no one will be able to help if you leave the question in that form.

Comment: Like Davis Carlisle says we need a minimal working example. [Here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) you can find more general information and here  ([MWE related informations](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: It is probably a bit early to flag this as unclear, but we will only be able to answer the question properly with more information. Ideally in form of an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I have now edited my question. @moewe

Comment: @RanveerSingh, document which add to question, is not very helpful. It contain to much errors and include files which we haven't. Please remove all errors and reduce it to really minimal working example, which still show your problem.

Comment: That is not really a minimal code example. We don't have all the `\include`d files and it throws way to many errors so that we can hardly focus on the real problem.

Comment: I am writing thesis, it contains around 10 files. I dont know how could I give the example in this case.

Comment: your problem is definition of `\titleformat{\section} ...`. remove `\MakeUppercase` in it and see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25150/using-makeuppercase-in-startsection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are not caused by `tikz` package but properties of `scrbook` regarding use of `\MakeUppercase` in definition of section style. For details see [Stefan Kottwitz answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25150/using-makeuppercase-in-startsection). Based on it, see if instead your definition of `\titleformat{\section}` the following

```
\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{13}{11}\selectfont\uppercase}% <-- observe difference
    {\sffamily\thesection}
    {0.2em}
    {}
```

gives what you expect:

[image]

Wit above definition I can compile your document without error (of course, I wrote chapters, section and subsection titles directly in document).

**Off-topic:** 
I must confess that I'm lost in your document. Do you realy need all those redefinition? By the way, your defining of font size with for example `\fontsize{14}{11}` is wrong. The firs number is font size, the second is baseline skip (which had to be bigger than font size) also is missing `\selectfont`. Why you not use simpler `small`, or `\large`, or `\Large` commands?

Comment: I am extremely thankful to you. My institute is new, we are making our own template of thesis, hence we are encountering lot of bugs.

Comment: @RanveerSingh, you are welcome. Happy TeXing