# What happened to expl3's case changing functions? (e.g. \tl_upper_case:n and \tl_lower_case:n)

Tags: expl3, latex3, token-lists

I had some `expl3` code which relied on `\tl_upper_case:n` to do some expandable case changing. However today I updated my TeX distribution and the code now throws an error:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: '\tl_upper_case:n' deprecated on 2022-01-01. Use
(LaTeX3)        '\text_uppercase:n '.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              

l.6 \tl_upper_case:n
                     { oh~no! }
?
```

In fact, all of:

```
\tl_<some>_case:n(n)    % <some> = (upper|lower|mixed)
\str_<some>_case:n      % <some> = (upper|lower|fold)
\char_<some>_case:N     % <some> = (upper|lower|mixed|fold)
\char_str_<some>_case:N % <some> = (upper|lower|mixed|fold)
```

raise similar errors. What happened?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error message says, the function `\tl_upper_case:n` are now deprecated and should be replaced by `\text_uppercase:n`. The full list is:

- `\tl_<some>_case:n(n)` → `\text_<some>case:n`, for `lower`, `upper`, and `mixed` case;
- `\str_<some>_case:n` → `\str_<some>case:n`, for `lower`, `upper`, and `fold` case;
- `\char_<some>_case:N` → `\char_<some>case:N`, for `lower`, `upper`, `mixed`, and `fold` case;
- `\char_str_<some>_case:N` → `\char_str_<some>case:N`, for `lower`, `upper`, `mixed`, and `fold` case.

In particular, `<some>_case` was replaced by `<some>case`, as a single word, `mixed` case was renamed to `title` case and, more importantly, the functions for dealing with general text input were removed from `l3tl` (token lists) to a more specific `l3text` module for general text manipulation tools.

You can read more about the text and string manipulation functions in the [“The `l3text` package”](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#part.33) part of the `expl3` interfaces documentation or in [this blog post](https://www.texdev.net/2020/01/15/case-changing-in-expl3), which contains a brief discussion of the main features of these functions, including language-dependent changes, with usage examples.

---

Until the mentioned update, the functions were (for four years or so) in the `l3tl` module as experimental features (thus subject to change), but they (the `\tl_<some>_case:n` ones) were not really suited for `l3tl` and there was the increasing need of a module for text manipulation. Now in the `l3text` module they are marked as stable, so there should be no further interface changes.

This move was the first step in a larger update to add other text manipulation tools to the LaTeX3 kernel. The base of these functions is the newly added `\text_expand:n`, which does as it advertises: it expands input text. This function is more or less equivalent to LaTeX2ε's `\protected@edef`, but it's powered by `\expanded`, so it's expandable!

More functions will be added to the new `l3text` module, for example `\text_purify:n`, which will be an expandable equivalent to `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdef` to generate valid PDF strings from user input.

Comment: I'd say `\text_expand:n` is a bit like a combination of `\expanded` with `\protected@edef` ...