# ! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \str_lowercase:nlatin

Tags: luatex

```
   \documentclass[bibliography=totoc, parskip=half, DIV=calc, 12pt, captions=tableheading]{scrartcl} 

   \usepackage{polyglossia}

   \setdefaultlanguage{german}

   \usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 

   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

   \pagestyle{scrheadings}

   %\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}

   %\addbibresource{nes.bib}

   \usepackage{booktabs}  

   \usepackage{romanbar}

   \usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

   \usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}

   \newtheorem{theorem}{Satz}
```

Can anybody see where I made the mistake that leads to this error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try updating `l3kernel`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/524346/134574

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. I updated MikTeX:)

Comment: That great! I'll mark your question as a duplicate of that one, if you don't mind.