# Why does \ifx consider \MakeUppercase{1} and \MakeLowercase{1} different?

Tags: conditionals, text-manipulation

In this minimal example, an uppercase number is different of the same lowercase number. Why?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\def\testone{\MakeUppercase{1}}
\def\testtwo{\MakeLowercase{1}}

\ifx\testone\testtwo
    Equal
\else
    Diff
\fi

\end{document}
```

Prints: Diff

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://xkcd.com/2206/) is why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like Donald Hosek said, `\ifx` doesn’t expand its arguments.  You’re comparing the unexpanded macros `\MakeUppercase{1}` and `\MakeLowercase{1}`.  You could fix this by fully expanding the macros you compare.

However, that doesn’t give you a complete solution, because `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` are not expandable.  So, `\edef\upperone{{\MakeUppercase 1}}` will fail.  You should instead use [the expl3 functions that are fully-expandable,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/are-there-purely-expandable-variants-of-makeuppercase) and that also support Unicode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
\ExplSyntaxOn
\edef\upone{\text_uppercase:n {1}}
\edef\lowone{\text_lowercase:n {1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
    
\begin{document}
{\upone} and {\lowone} are
\ifx\upone\lowone
  identical.
\else
  different.
\fi
    
\end{document}
```

This gives you, “1 and 1 are identical.”

#### Edit

Joseph Wright brings up that you might really be after a case-insensitive comparison.  For that, you should be using [`\str_fold_case:n`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#section.7.7), which supports Unicode on LuaTeX or XeTeX, but only ASCII on PDFTeX.

Comment: All fair, but `\text_<name>case:n` is for typesetting. I suspect the comparison is string-based here, and even more so it's often the case that's what really wanted is case-folding.

Comment: @JosephWright Very possible!

Comment: @DonaldHosek Apologies for the typo in your name! Good answer, too, although I wanted to expand on it with a solution.

Answer (score 11):

You're going to get different results because you're comparing the definitions of the two macros. `\MakeUppercase{1}` is not the same as `\MakeLowercase{1}` It's worth noting that the `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` macros are themselves complicated enough that the naïve approaches to trying to expand them to get the results in plain text will still not give expected results (so doing, e.g., `\edef` or multiple `\expandafter`s won't get you what you might have been hoping for).

Comment: So, what's the best way to compare strings without macro interferences?

Comment: For most things, what you've done would work fine. The problem is with `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` whose output is not a simple string—note, for example, that it has to be able to handle things like correctly uppercasing `na\"\i ve` to `NA\"IVE`, to pick one example. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7):

The test fails to show equality on (at least) two levels.

#### First level

`\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` are instructions to *print* the uppercased or lowercased versions of their arguments. They don't “directly” transform their arguments.

#### Second level

`\ifx` only compares the “surface meaning” of two tokens without any macro expansion. In particular, two macros (every token defined with `\def` is a macro) are considered equal by `\ifx` if and only if

1. they have the same status with respect to `\long`, `\outer` and `\protected`;
2. their parameter texts are the same;
3. their top level expansions are equal.

In your case subtests 1 and 2 pass, but subtest 3 doesn't, because the top level expansions are

```
\MakeUppercase{1}
```

and

```
\MakeLowercase{1}
```

respectively, which are different sequences of tokens.

---

A perhaps simpler example is given by

```
\def\firstX{X}
\def\secondX{X}
\def\testA{\firstX}
\def\testB{\secondX}
```

The conditional `\ifx\firstX\secondX` will return true, but `\ifx\testA\testB` will return false.

Another example: with

```
\def\first#1{#1}
\def\second#1{#1}
\def\testA{\first{X}}
\def\testB{\second{X}}
```

the conditional `\ifx\testA\testB` will return false because the top level expansions of `\testA` and `\testB` are different even if ultimately `\first{X}` and `\second{X}` will deliver the same result. But TeX doesn't look at the “ultimate” effect when doing `\ifx` comparisons, just the surface.