# Function like macro?

Tags: tex-core

If you have programmed in a high level programming language, you must be familiar with the concept of functions, subroutines which return a value. For example, if you write in C, you can write a function to compute the absolute value of an integer parameter

```
int abs(int a) { 
    return a > 0 ? a: -a; 
}
```

You can invoke this function, assigning its result to a variable, by writing e.g.,

```
int v = abs(a)`
```

Furthermore, you can use the returned value directly, without assigning it to a variable, e.g.,

```
abs(abs(a)-abs(b))
```

What's the closest you can get to this with TeX programming? The challenge is in minimizing the coupling between the caller and the callee. Of course, since TeX is primarily about characters and textual tokens, a more natural example would be something of the sort of the chain of function calls in:

```
int ispalindrome(const char *s) {
   return strcmp(s, strrev(s)) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a computer science point of view, macros *are* functions. The issue here is rather that TeX doesn’t offer many maths and string processing directives. But assuming we had these functions, your `abs` function could be directly translated into a macro definition (either TeXish or LaTeXish):

```
\def\abs#1{%
  \ifgreater{#1}{0}{#1}{\neg{#1}}}
```

(In fact, TeX has `\ifnum`:

```
\def\abs#1{%
  \ifnum#1>0\relax#1\else\neg{#1}\fi}
```

)

And can be invoked:

```
\abs{42}
```

And nested:

```
\abs{\minus{\abs{a}}{\abs{b}}}
```

Comment: Konrad: I think this is a very interesting and valuable perspective, that is, of thinking of every macro as function which returns a result, namely the list of tokens it expands into.

Comment: I like the translated-to-english premise in `\ifnum#1>0\relax#1` "If the number is greater than zero, just relax, sit back, have a poolside cocktail and output `#1`. All is well."

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT (three years later)** Answering this question has led to a complete reimplementation of floating point calculations in LaTeX3.

There are two types of (complex) macros in TeX: those ("expandable" macros) which work purely by expansion, turning their argument into something else without ever needing to store an intermediate result or otherwise affect the state of the TeX machine, and those ("non-expandable" macros) which alter the state.

TeX proper only computes with integers non-expandably, through `\advance`, `\multiply` and `\divide`, essentially `+=`, `*=`, and `//=`.  These assignments are non-expandable.  Instead of simply doing `2+3*4+5` or `\add{\add{2}{\mul{3}{4}}}{5}` one must do the equivalent of

```
x = 2
y = 3
y *= 4
x += y
x += 5
```

using intermediate variables, which is unpractical.  The eTeX primitive `\numexpr` lets us evaluate expandably expressions which involve integers, `(`, `)`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.  As Joseph describes, it lets us define function-like macros

```
\def\add#1#2{\the\numexpr(#1)*(#2)\relax}
\def\abs#1{\the\numexpr\ifnum\numexpr#1<0-\fi(#1)\relax}
\add{\abs{-3}}{4} % = 7
```

Many packages (`pgfmath`, `fp`, ...) provide non-expandable macros to compute with floating point numbers, with varying levels of practicality.  Since last year, `l3fp` evaluates floating point expressions expandably.  A typical example:

```
\fp_eval:n { abs(-3)+4*ln(5.6e7) }
```

For historical purposes, I've left the code for a prototype of l3fp below.

**EDIT (2011)** I had written a parsing step for more user-friendliness, but it was buggy, so I removed it. I also rewrote the code completely a few times and implemented subtraction and division.  The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% ====
% Floating point numbers which we'll call ``<ZBfp>'', of the form
%   <sign> {<int>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}T{<int expr>}
% where 
%   <sign> is "+" or "-" (mandatory)
%   <int> is at most 4 digits, and never equal to zero (except cases below)
%   <4d> represents 4 digits exactly
%   <int expr> is something that "\number\numexpr...\relax" is happy with.
%
% Exceptions: 
% - The <sign> can also be "X" for undefined.
%       X{0000}{0000}{0000}{0000}T{0}
% This is converted to a sign of "+" if we use it further in the calculation.
%       +{0000}{0000}{0000}{0000}T{0}
%
% Example:
%   + {0234}{2345}{3456}{4567}T{0} means   234.234534564567
%   - {1111}{2222}{3333}{4444}T{2} means -111122223333.4444
% 
% ==== Helpers
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_brace_last:nw #1 #2 #{#1{#2}}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 # { #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 {#6} }
\cs_new:Npn \use_Bi_iiE:nn #1 #2 { {#1 #2} }
\cs_new:Npn \use_iv_delimit_by_q_stop:nnnnw #1#2#3#4#5\q_stop {#4}
\tl_const:Nn \c_ZBfp_braced_plus_tl { {+} }
\tl_const:Nn \c_ZBfp_braced_minus_tl { {-} }

% Constants
\tl_const:Nn \c_zero_ZBfp {+{0000}{0000}{0000}{0000}T{0}}
\tl_const:Nn \c_undefined_ZBfp {X{0000}{0000}{0000}{0000}T{0}}

% ==== Adding mantissas.
%
% Used as
%     \ZBfp_add_mantissa:nnnnnnnn {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}
%         {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>} {<sign>} T {<exp>}
% to get 
%     <sign> {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>} T{<exp>}
%
% We split numbers efficiently by pre-carrying.
% Note that all the extra "-1", "+9999", "10000" sum up to zero.
% Also, it would be more efficient to replace those constants by registers?
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add_mantissa:nnnnnnnn #1#2#3#4 #5#6#7#8{
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_add_mantissa_aux:N
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D             -1 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #1 + #5 + 9999 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #2 + #6 + 9999 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #3 + #7 + 9999 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #4 + #8 + 10000
}
% Important: that "#8" above is followed by a brace group, \marg{sign}.

% We are left with 
%     "\ZBfp_add_mantissa_aux:N" <1d>{4d}{4d}{4d}{4d}{<sign>}T{<exp>}
% where <1d> is either "0" or "1", the overall carry.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add_mantissa_aux:N #1 {
  \if_meaning:w 0 #1 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_add_mantissa_aux_z:nnnnnnw
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_add_mantissa_aux_i:nnnnnnw
  \fi:
  #1
}
% If the first digit is "0", we discard it and keep four brace groups.
% Otherwise, we keep it in a brace group, together with three more.
% In both cases, we place the sign and the exponent at the right place.
% Note that the exponent is not evaluated. 
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add_mantissa_aux_z:nnnnnnw #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 T #7 {
  #6     {#2}{#3}{#4}{#5} T{#7} }
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add_mantissa_aux_i:nnnnnnw #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 T #7 {
  #6 {000 #1}{#2}{#3}{#4} T{#7+1} }

% ===== Subtracting mantissa
% Used as
%     \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa:nnnnnnnn <A> <B> {<sign>} T {<exp>}
% where <A> and <B> have the form {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}. This
% calculates $<sign>*( - <A> + <B> )$ (hence the name "back") and
% f-expands to the result in the form
%     <sign> {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>} T{<exp>}
%
% Again, pre-carrying. We check after the calculation if the 
% subtraction should have been done in the other direction.
% Thus, doing subtraction as - <big mantissa> + <small mantissa> 
% should be twice slower than the other way around, but that's
% the price to pay to get a more optimized subtraction
% - <small> + <big>, used more frequently in the ``full'' 
% subtraction and in sines. 
%
% We use bigger shifts that we had for addition, because we want
% to ensure that every intermediate numexpr we use has five digits
% for "\ZBfp_brace_last:nw" to work. 
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa:nnnnnnnn #1#2#3#4 #5#6#7#8 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_aux:w
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #5 - #1 - 2     + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #6 - #2 + 19998 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #7 - #3 + 19998 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #8 - #4 + 20000 
}
% Again, following "#8" is a brace group, \marg{sign}.
% We are left with 
%     "\ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_aux:w" <w>{4d}{4d}{4d}{<sign>}T{<exp>},
% where <w> is any integer between -9999 and +9999. Here we need to take
% care of the fact that e.g. -11{2222}{2222}{2222} means 
% "-11 + .222222222222", not "-11.222222222222"! Convince yourself
% that if <w> is zero, then we are in the ``positive'' case.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_aux:w #1 #{
  \if_num:w #1 < 0 \exp_stop_f:
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_neg:nnnnn
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_pos:nnnn
  \fi:
  {#1}
}
% \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_neg:nnnnn {-<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>} {<sign>} T {<exp>}
% If the result of the subtraction was negative, then we need
% to correct it and correct the sign.
%
% > "#1", "#2", "#3", "#4" form the body of the number
% > "#5" is the <sign>
% > "#6" would be the exponent expression
%
% Here, we know that "#1" is negative. In fact, our number is 
% equal to <sign>"(#1 + .#2#3#4)". We calculate "|#1|-.#2#3#4", 
% which is positive, and place the correct sign (namely, $-$<sign>)
% in a brace group after it, then pass the whole thing to 
% "\ZBfp_add_mantissa_pos:nnnnnw".
%
% Once more, pre-carry, to make sure everything has 5 digits when passed
% to "\ZBfp_brace_last:nw".
%
% On the first piece below, "-2 - #1 + ...". From the level below 
% (i.e. the "..."), we get "1", or sometimes "2", and we know that
% "10000<#1<0", so the whole thing is "0<=...<10000", at most 4 digits.
%
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_neg:nnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_pos:nnnn
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D    -2 - #1 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D 19998 - #2 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D 19998 - #3 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D 20000 - #4 
  \if:w -#5 
      \exp_after:wN \c_ZBfp_braced_plus_tl 
  \else: 
      \exp_after:wN \c_ZBfp_braced_minus_tl  
  \fi:
}
% Note that the final line gets fully expanded to "{+}" or "{-}" 
% when \TeX\ is trying to finish the number "#4". Specifically, the sign
% we get is the opposite of "#5". Any faster test (braces are important)?

% "\ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_pos:nnnn" {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>} {<sign>} T {<exp>}
% Once we have taken care of the signs, we need to check whether 
% the first, second, etc. pieces is/are zero, and shift exponents
% accordingly. 
% > "#1", "#2", "#3", "#4" form the body of the number,
% > "#5" is the sign
% > "#7" is the exponent 
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa_pos:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 {
    \cs:w ZBfp_sub_maux_
        \if_num:w #1 = 0 \exp_stop_f:             i
            \if_num:w #2 = 0 \exp_stop_f:         i
                \if_num:w #3 = 0 \exp_stop_f:     i 
                    \if_num:w #4 = 0 \exp_stop_f: i
                    \fi:
                \fi:
            \fi:
        \fi:
        :w
    \cs_end:
    {#1}
    {#2}
    {#3}
    {#4}
}
% Just reformat digits in the right way.
\cs_new:Npx\ZBfp_sub_maux_iiii:w #1#2#3#4 #5T#6 {\c_zero_ZBfp}
\cs_new:Npn\ZBfp_sub_maux_iii:w#1#2#3#4 #5T#6 {#5 {#4}{0000}{0000}{0000}T{#6-3}}
\cs_new:Npn\ZBfp_sub_maux_ii:w #1#2#3#4 #5T#6 {#5 {#3} {#4} {0000}{0000}T{#6-2}}
\cs_new:Npn\ZBfp_sub_maux_i:w  #1#2#3#4 #5T#6 {#5 {#2} {#3}  {#4} {0000}T{#6-1}}
\cs_new:Npn\ZBfp_sub_maux_:w   #1#2#3#4 #5T#6 {#5 {#1} {#2}  {#3}  {#4} T {#6} }

% ======= Full addition and subtraction.
% Syntax:
%   "\ZBfp_add:nn" \marg{ZBfp expr.} \marg{ZBfp expr.}
%   "\ZBfp_sub:nn" \marg{ZBfp expr.} \marg{ZBfp expr.}
% where <ZBfp> are floating point expressions, which will be 
% fully f-expanded before the calculation.
% Plan:
% > expand the left <ZBfp expr.>
% > swap, and expand the right <ZBfp expr.>
% > check signs 
% > shift digits according to exponent
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add:nn #1 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_add_aux:NwNn 
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #1 \q_stop +
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_sub:nn #1 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_add_aux:NwNn 
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #1 \q_stop -
}
% We now have
%    "\ZBfp_add_aux:NwNn" <sign A> <A> T {<eA>} \q_stop <operation> {<expr B>}
% Here <sign A> <A> T {<eA>} is our first floating point number:
% <A> is the body, {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}, and <eA> is the exponent. 
% Also, <operation> is "+" or "-". 
% We then move <expr B> to the front and f-expand it.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add_aux:NwNn #1 #2 \q_stop #3 #4 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_add_signs:NNN \exp_after:wN #1 \exp_after:wN #3
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #4 #2
}
% We now have
%    "\ZBfp_add_aux:NwNn" <sign A> <operation> <sign B> <B>T{<eB>} <A>T{<eA>}
% If the product <sign A><operation><sign B> is +, 
% use "\ZBfp_add_exponent:w", else "\ZBfp_sub_exponent:w".
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add_signs:NNN #1 #2 #3 {
  \cs:w ZBfp_
      \if:w #1 \if:w #2 #3 + \else: - \fi: add \else: sub \fi:
  _exponent:w \cs_end:
  #1
}
% We now have "\ZBfp_..._exponent:w" <sign A> <B>T{<eB>} <A>T{<eA>}
% Take care of exponents. If they are the same, do nothing. 
% If they differ, shift in the relevant direction using
% "\ZBfp_decimate_do". We first check the equality case 
% because we will arrange to be in that case for our calculations 
% of sine and cosine (which we want to optimize).
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_add_exponent:w #1 #2 T #3 #4 T #5 {
    \if_num:w #3 > #5 \exp_stop_f:
        \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn
    \else: 
        \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn
    \fi:
    { 
      \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_decimate_do:nNnnnn \exp_after:wN {
        \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #3 - #5 } 
      \ZBfp_add_mantissa:nnnnnnnn #4 #2 {#1} T {#3} 
    }
    { 
      \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_decimate_do:nNnnnn \exp_after:wN {
        \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #5 - #3 }
      \ZBfp_add_mantissa:nnnnnnnn #2 #4 {#1} T {#5} 
    }
}
% "\ZBfp_decimate_do:nNnnnn {<shift>} <func> {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}
% will shift the blocks of digits by <shift> blocks to the right, 
% adding "{0000}" blocks at the start when shifting, then place
% <func> in front of 4 blocks of 4 digits. Requires $<shift> \geq 0$.
% When shifting results in a zero number, instead of performing the
% computation, we simply remove <func> and the 4 blocks of digits,
% presumably leaving only the other operand on the input stream.
% In other words, if the difference in exponent is ${}>3$, the small
% number is to small ($10000^{-4}$), and we throw it away.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_decimate_do:nNnnnn #1 {
    \if_case:w #1 \exp_stop_f:
    % zero shift: do nothing.
    \or:   \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_decimate_i:Nnnnn
    \or:   \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_decimate_ii:Nnnnn
    \or:   \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_decimate_iii:Nnnnn
    \else: \exp_after:wN \use_none:nnnnn
    \fi:
}
% "\ZBfp_decimate_1:w" <func> {<4d>} {<4d>} {<4d>} {<4d>}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_decimate_i:Nnnnn   #1 #2#3#4#5 {#1 {0000} {#2}  {#3} {#4}}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_decimate_ii:Nnnnn  #1 #2#3#4#5 {#1 {0000}{0000} {#2} {#3}}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_decimate_iii:Nnnnn #1 #2#3#4#5 {#1 {0000}{0000}{0000}{#2}}

% "\ZBfp_sub_exponent:w" <sign A> <B>T{<eB>} <A>T{<eA>}
% For subtraction, signs are tricky. Given the above, we want to
% calculate $<sign A>*(<A>*10000^{<eA>} - <B>*10000^{<eB>})$.
% \begin{itemize}
% \item 
%   If $ <eB> \leq <eA> $, then we will ``decimate'' <B> (possibly
%   with a zero <shift> when there is equality), and essentially 
%   calculate "sub_back" <B'> <A> <sign A> T {<eA>}, where <B'> is 
%   the result of decimating. That gives 
%   $ <sign A> * (- <B> + <A>) * 10000^{<eA>} $.
% \item
%   Otherwise, we need to change the sign. Unfortunately, that sign 
%   has to be sent quite deep (just before the "T" of the exponent).
%   Maybe that could be improved, but right now, we first calculate
%   the correct sign and place it at the right spot using 
%   "\ZBfp_sub_exponent_aux:Nw". Some will complain that the 
%   conditional is not terminated when placing the sign, but no worry,
%   it gets terminated since we just continue executing things after
%   placing the sign.
%
%   Then decimate <A>. And calculate "sub_back" <A'> <B> {- <sign A>} T {<eB>},
%   which is equal to $ - <sign A> *(-<A>+<B>) * 10000^{<eB>}$.
% \end{itemize}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_sub_exponent:w #1 #2 T #3 #4 T #5 {
    \if_num:w #3 > #5 \exp_stop_f:
        \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn
    \else: 
        \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn
    \fi:
    { 
      \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_sub_exponent_aux:Nw \if:w -#1 + \else: - \fi:
      \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_decimate_do:nNnnnn \exp_after:wN {
        \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #3 - #5 }
      \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa:nnnnnnnn #4 #2 T {#3} 
    }
    { 
      \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_decimate_do:nNnnnn \exp_after:wN {
        \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #5 - #3 }
      \ZBfp_sub_back_mantissa:nnnnnnnn #2 #4 {#1} T {#5} 
    }
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_sub_exponent_aux:Nw #1 #2 T {#2 {#1} T}
% ===== Multiplication
% Syntax:
%   "\ZBfp_mul:nn" \marg{ZBfp expr.} \marg{ZBfp expr.}
% First expand the first expression, then swap, and expand the
% second expression. Then treat exponents and place the sign at 
% the right place.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul:nn #1 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_mul_aux:Nwn 
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #1 \q_stop
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul_aux:Nwn #1 \q_stop #2 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_mul_signs_expo:NwnNwn
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #2 #1
}
% The signs are "#1" and "#4", "#3" and "#6" are the exponents, and
% each "#2" and "#5" are 16 digits split in blocks of 4.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul_signs_expo:NwnNwn #1 #2 T#3 #4 #5 T#6 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_mul_mantissa:wnnnnnnnn 
  \exp_after:wN #1 
  \exp_after:wN #4 
  \exp_after:wN T 
  \exp_after:wN {\tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #3 + #6}
  \q_stop
  #2 #5
}
% Now we have 
%   "\ZBfp_mul_mantissa:wnnnnnnnn" <sign><sign> T {<exp>} \q_stop
%       {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>} {<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}{<4d>}
% TODO: Round instead of truncating, by adapting one of the "99990000" shifts
% to something like "50000000" and review "\ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux_signs"
% once that is done.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul_mantissa:wnnnnnnnn #1\q_stop #2#3#4#5 #6#7#8#9 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux:w
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D          -10000 +
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D        99990000 + #2*#6 + 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D        99990000 + #2*#7+#3*#6+ 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D        99990000 + #2*#8+#3*#7+#4*#6+ 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D        99990000 + #2*#9+#3*#8+#4*#7+#5*#6 + 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D        99990000 + #3*#9+#4*#8+#5*#7+ 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D        99990000 + #4*#9+#5*#8 + 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D       100000000 + #5*#9
  \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux_signs:NN #1
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux_signs:NN #1 #2 {
  \if:w #1 #2 
  \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn 
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn
  \fi:
  { {} \q_stop {+} }
  { {} \q_stop {-} }
}
% We are left with
%    "\ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux:w 
%         <int>{4d}{4d}{4d}{4d}...{4d}{}\q_stop{<sign>}T{<exp>}"
% where <int> (positive) may range from 0 to 9999. If it is zero, 
% we need to remove it and shift the exponent. But we know that
% <int> is in its simplest form, since it comes from a "numexpr" 
% calculation, so <int>=0 is equivalent to having its first character
% equal to 0 (I guess "\if_meaning:w" is quicker than "\if_num:w"
% because it involves no expansion).
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux:w #1 #{
  \if_meaning:w 0 #1
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux_z:nnnnnnww
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux_i:nnnnnww
  \fi:
  {#1}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux_z:nnnnnnww #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 \q_stop #7 T#8 {
  #7 {#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}T{#8}}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_mul_mantissa_aux_i:nnnnnww #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 \q_stop #6 T#7 {
  #6 {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}T{#7+1}}

% ===== Division [not tested properly!]
% Syntax:
%   "\ZBfp_div:nn" \marg{ZBfp expr.} \marg{ZBfp expr.}
% First expand the first expression, then swap, and expand the
% second expression. Then treat exponents and place the sign at 
% the right place.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div:nn #1 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_aux:Nwn 
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #1 \q_stop
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_aux:Nwn #1 \q_stop #2 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_check_zero:ww
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #2 \q_stop #1 \q_stop
}
% First let's check if the numerator or denominator is zero.
% Note that "#1" is the denominator!
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_check_zero:ww #1 \q_stop #2 \q_stop {
  \ZBfp_if_zero_aux:NnnnnwNN #1 \use_i_delimit_by_q_stop:nw \use_none:n 
                                {\c_undefined_ZBfp}
  \ZBfp_if_zero_aux:NnnnnwNN #2 \use_i_delimit_by_q_stop:nw \use_none:n 
                                {\c_zero_ZBfp}
  \ZBfp_div_i:Nn #1 #2
  \q_stop
}
% We strip leading zeros from the denominator (specifically <B0>).
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_i:Nn #1 #2 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_ii:NnnnnwNww 
  \exp_after:wN #1 
  \exp_after:wN {\tex_number:D #2}
}

% "\ZBfp_div_ii:NnnnnwNww" 
%     <Bsign> {<trimmed B0>}{<B1>}{<B2>}{<B3>} T {<Bexp>}
%     <Asign> {<A0>}{<A1>}{<A2>}{<A3>} T {<Aexp>} \q_stop
% We grab the whole body of <A> as one argument.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_ii:NnnnnwNww #1 #2#3#4#5T#6 #7 #8T#9 \q_stop{
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_iii:nnnnnnnnn \tex_number:D #2 \exp_stop_f: 
  #3 #4 #5 0000\q_stop % <B>, unpacked
  #8                   % <A>, in blocks of 4
  #1 #7               % signs
  T {#9 - (#6)}       % exponent
  Z {\use_none:nnnn #2 000} % extra zeros compensating the power.
}

% Repack <B>.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_iii:nnnnnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9 {
  \ZBfp_div_iiii:nnnnnw {{#1#2#3#4#5}{#6#7#8#9}}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_iiii:nnnnnw #1 #2#3#4#5 #6 \q_stop {
  \ZBfp_div_v:nwnn #1 {#2#3#4#5} \q_stop
}
% Now we have
% "\ZBfp_div_v:nwnn" {<B'0>}{<B'1>}{<B'2>} \q_stop
%        {<A0>}{<A1>}{<A2>}{<A3>} <Bsign><Asign> T{<exp>} Z{<zeros>}
%
% where each of <Ai> and <B'i> have 4 digits, except <B'0>, which
% has exactly 5 digits.
% 
% We will now use as a quotient
% \[
%   <Q0> = \operatorname{Round} \frac{<A0><A1>}{<B'0>+1} - 1.
% \]
% The extra $+1$ and $-1$ are needed to make sure that everything 
% stays positive.\footnote{Better ideas are welcome!} The numerator
% of <Q0> is between $10^4$ and $10^8$. The denominator is
% between $10^4$ and $10^5$. So $-1\leq <Q0> \leq 10^4$.
% 
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_v:nwnn #1 #2 \q_stop #3 #4 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_vi:nnnnnnn \exp_after:wN 
  {
    \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #3#4 / (#1+1) - 1   
  }
  {#1} #2 {#3 #4}
}
% We calculate $<A> - <Q0>*<B'>$.
% 
% "\ZBfp_div_vi:nnnnnnn" {<Q0>} {<B'0>}{<B'1>}{<B'2>} 
%            {<A0><A1>}{<A2>}{<A3>} <Bsign><Asign> T{<exp>} Z{<zeros>}
% 
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_vi:nnnnnnn #1 #2#3#4 #5#6#7 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_vii:nnn
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D  (#5 - #1*#2)*10000 + #6 - #1*#3 - 20000 + 
  \exp_after:wN 
  \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D  200000000 + #7 - #1*#4 
  {#2}{#3}{#4} {#1}
}
% The term in parentheses is 
% \begin{align*}
%   <A0><A1> - <Q0>*<B'0> 
%   &= <A0><A1> - \frac{<B'0>}{<B'0>+1} <A0><A1> + \alpha <B'0>
%   \\
%   &= \frac{<A0><A1>}{<B'0>+1} + \alpha <B'0>
% \end{align*}
% where $1/2 \leq \alpha \leq 3/2$ (because of e\TeX's rounding 
% and our $-1$). This is at most $10^4 + 1.5*<B'0> \leq 1.5\cdot 10^5$.
% Multiplying by $10^4$ won't overflow (but it can be quite close).
%
% All in all, the result should be some long number <s1s2> obeying
% $<s1s2> \leq 15000\cdot<B'0>$ (more or less).

% "\ZBfp_div_vii:nnn" {<s1s2>}{<s3>} {<B'0>}{<B'1>}{<B'2>} {<Q0>}
%           <Bsign><Asign> T{<exp>} Z{<zeros>}
%
% We need to be very careful, because <s1s2> can be up to $1.5*10^9$,
% close to overflow. Calculate the next quotient
% \[
%   <Q1> = \operatorname{Round} \frac{<s1s2>}{<B'0> + 1} - 1.
% \]
% A few lines above, we get $<s1s2> \leq 15000\cdot <B'0> + 10^8$,
% so $<Q1> \leq 15000 + 10^8/<B'0> \leq 25000$ or so.
% 
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_vii:nnn #1 #2 #3 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_viii:nnnnnnn \exp_after:wN 
  {
    \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #1/(#3 + 1) - 1 
  }
  {#1} {#2} {#3}
}
% "\ZBfp_div_viii:nnnnnnn" {<Q1>} {<s1s2>}{<s3>} {<B'0>}{<B'1>}{<B'2>} 
%           {<Q0>} <Bsign><Asign> T{<exp>} Z{<zeros>}
% 
% We now add one level down, to keep enough precision. 
% Not sure I'm doing that rigt.
% 
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_viii:nnnnnnn #1 #2#3 #4#5#6 #7 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_ix:nnn
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D  (#2 - #1*#4)*10000 + #3 - #1*#5 - 30000 + 
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nnnnnw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D  300000000 - #1*#6
  {#4} {#5} {#7} {#1}
}
% we won't need <B'2> anymore, so we drop "#6".

% "\ZBfp_div_ix:nnn" {<t1t2>}{<t3>} {<B'0>}{<B'1>} {<Q0>}{<Q1>} 
%           <Bsign><Asign> T{<exp>} Z{<zeros>}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_ix:nnn #1#2 #3 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_x:nnnnnnn \exp_after:wN 
  {
    \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #1/(#3 + 1) - 1 
  }
  {#1} {#2} {#3}
}
% "\ZBfp_div_x:nnnnnnn" {<Q2>} {<t1t2>}{<t3>} {<B'0>}{<B'1>} {<Q0>}{<Q1>} 
%           <Bsign><Asign> T{<exp>} Z{<zeros>}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_x:nnnnnnn #1 #2#3 #4#5 #6#7 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_xi:nnnnnww 
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D  (#2 - #1*#4)*10000 + #3 - #1*#5
  {#4} {#6}{#7}{#1}
}
% "\ZBfp_div_xi:nnnnn" {<u>} {<B'0>} {<Q0>}{<Q1>}{<Q2>}
%           <Bsign><Asign> T{<exp>} Z{<zeros>}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_xi:nnnnnww #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 T#7 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_xii:nnnnw
  \tex_romannumeral:D \etex_numexpr:D -1 + \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D 9999 + #3 +  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D 9999 + #4 +  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D 9999 + #5 +  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_brace_last:nw
  \tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D 10000 + #1 / #2
  \exp_after:wN {\tex_the:D \etex_numexpr:D #7\exp_after:wN} #6
}
% "\ZBfp_div_xii:nnnnw" {<Q0>}{<Q1>}{<Q2>}{<Q3>} {<exp>}
%           <Bsign><Asign> Z{<zeros>}
% now the <zeros> are explicitly "000" or "00" or "0" or " ",
% and each <Qi> is 4 digits.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_xii:nnnnw #1#2#3#4 #5 Z#6 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_repack_i:nnnnnnnn #6 #1#2#3#4 0000\q_stop #5
}
% "\ZBfp_div_repack_i:nnnnnnnn" <20-23 digits> \q_stop
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_repack_i:nnnnnnnn #1#2#3#4 #5#6#7#8 {
  \if_num:w #1#2#3#4 = \c_zero
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_repack_ii_small:nnNNNNNNN
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_div_repack_ii_large:nnNNNNNNN
  \fi:
  {#1#2#3#4} {#5#6#7#8}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_repack_ii_large:nnNNNNNNN #1 #2 #3#4#5#6 #7#8#9 {
  \ZBfp_div_repack_iii_large:nnnnNw {#1} {#2} {#3#4#5#6} {#7#8#9}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_repack_iii_large:nnnnNw #1 #2 #3 #4#5 #6\q_stop #7 #8#9{
  \if:w #8#9
  \exp_after:wN +
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN -
  \fi:
  {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4#5} T{#7}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_repack_ii_small:nnNNNNNNN #1 #2 #3#4#5#6 #7#8#9 {
  \ZBfp_div_repack_iii_small:nnnNNNNNw {#2} {#3#4#5#6} {#7#8#9}
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_repack_iii_small:nnnNNNNNw #1 #2 #3#4 #5#6#7#8 #9\q_stop{
  \ZBfp_div_repack_iv_small:nnNN { {#1} {#2} {#3#4} {#5#6#7#8} }
}
% "\ZBfp_div_repack_iv_small:nnNN" {<digits>} {<exp>} <sign><sign>
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_div_repack_iv_small:nnNN #1 #2 #3#4 {
  \if:w #3#4
  \exp_after:wN +
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN -
  \fi:
  #1 T{#2-1}
}

% ===== Absolute value
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_abs:n #1 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_abs_aux:N \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #1 
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_abs_aux:N #1 {+}

% ===== Negate
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_neg:n #1 {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_neg_aux:N \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #1
}
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_neg_aux:N #1 {
  \if:w - #1 
    \exp_after:wN + 
  \else: 
    \exp_after:wN - 
  \fi:
}

% ===== Test for zero
% All of the functions below are based on one auxiliary function.
\cs_new:Npn \ZBfp_if_zero_aux:NnnnnwNN #1 #2#3#4#5 T#6 #7#8 {
  \if_num:w \etex_numexpr:D #2#3+#4#5 = \c_zero
  \exp_after:wN #7
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN #8
  \fi:
}
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \ZBfp_if_zero:n #1 {p,T,F,TF} {
  \ZBfp_if_zero_aux:NnnnnwNN #1 
  \prg_return_true: \prg_return_false:
}
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \ZBfp_if_zero:f #1 {p,T,F,TF} {
  \exp_after:wN \ZBfp_if_zero_aux:NNNnnnnw 
  \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0 #1
  \prg_return_true: \prg_return_false:
}
\begin{document}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_term:n {f}
\iow_term:f { \ZBfp_mul:nn 
  {\ZBfp_add:nn {+{1234}{0000}{0000}{0000}T{2}} {+{0034}{5678}{0000}{0000}T{3}}}
  {\ZBfp_add:nn {+{1111}{1111}{1111}{1111}T{0}} {+{2222}{2222}{2222}{2222}T{1}}}
}
\iow_term:f { 
  \ZBfp_div:nn 
  {-{0001}{2309}{8124}{3772}T{2}} 
  {+{2384}{7623}{4098}{1230}T{-2}} 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect this will highlight my 'performance' point nicely :-) Also, while it solves the question at hand there are limits (I don't fancy doing something like sine in an expandable manner, for example!)

Comment: @Joseph: once the basic operations are done, the sine is just a matter of using a Taylor expansion like you did in l3fp :), since we can nest all these `\add` etc. And I think that an optimized expandable version would beat an optimized assignment-full version, since in the end the calculations are the same. (However, in terms of maintainability, the story is different.)

Comment: @Bruno: I'm perfectly happy to try some performance tests to see. You did notice that there is more to doing trigonometric functions than just a Taylor series, I guess. (Not just at the moment - I've got other stuff on, but perhaps at some stage. One reason for storing with functions such as sine is that _repeated_ application of the same function then gains a _lot_ of speed.)

Comment: @Bruno: Maintainability is an awkward one with floating-point functions as it is, as for performance reasons you do need to stick to primitives. As it is I suspect I need to remove some `\expandafter` use in `l3fp`.

Comment: @Joseph: don't do performance tests with the current version of the code above: it is not very optimized :). I see it more as a proof of concept. --- One possible approach would be to have elementary operations carried expandably, but still do the trigonometric ones non-expandably, if only for the sake of storing the results, as you said. --- By the way, why cut into blocks of 3 in your code, rather than 4? `\numexpr` is happy until `2e9`.

Comment: @Bruno. Because 1 + 9 digits in total needs three block for the decimal part, so I may as well use three the same size.

Comment: @Joseph. Instead of choosing the precision and then the implementation, I went the other way around, so 12=4+4+4 digits in total. For internal calculations, you use 1+9+9 digits?

Comment: @Bruno: No, 1+9+3 (_i.e._ one additional 'block'). The problem with 4 + 4 + 4 is that you then need to do a shift to get back to scientific notation at the end (1 + 9 e 2).

Comment: @Bruno: I'm not saying it's ideal. The current approach is more-or-less a floating-point version of the code in the `fp` package, with a few optimisations to gain some speed.

Comment: @Bruno: Feel free to write a better version of `l3fp` and I'll add it to the SVN :-)

Comment: @Joseph: I'll take a look some day. I'm not yet sure how to do subtraction or division, but otherwise, I'd go for 1+4+4+4 in internal computations. --- But first, I need to make some supervisors happy. And put together my expandable optional argument code with your brace matching in `xparse` if you don't get time before me :). Waiting to see what happens to the code for `\::e` on LaTeX-L as well.

Comment: @Bruno: I should add that your code is currently unable to handle things like `.1`, which might reasonably be regarded as valid input.

Comment: This is an *incredible* amount of code for an answer to this question!

Comment: @Bruno I would love to see a test based on my example in terms of performance. My hat off to you though for some incredible code, if not entertaining:)

Comment: @Will: yes, I got carried away. I thought "this should be easy enough", but I was _very_ wrong. --- Thankfully, the site crops long chuncks of code :).

Comment: @Yiannis: I haven't implemented power yet. And I have no idea how to do it. Even subtraction and division are non-trivial tasks, for which I'll have to read someone else's code (e.g., Joseph's l3fp).

Comment: @Joseph: I am now at twice the speed of l3fp for the sine, with no check, keeping the terms x+(x^3/6)+(x^5/120)+(x^7/5040). What proportion of the time do checks vs. calculations take in your code?

Comment: @Bruno: No idea. The `l3fp` speed testing was done using loops (I think I did 10000 repetitions for sine, deliberated deleting the stored values as part of the loop), with about 100 000 repetitions for division and perhaps 500 000 for addition. These were all of the order of 10-20 s on my PC using `time`. I am quite serious about re-implementing things for `l3fp`, by the way - as long as it gives the right output, the back-end can be done in a number of ways, and `l3fp` is still very much new code.

Comment: @Bruno: You mention above subtraction. That's actually pretty easy, as it's just addition with the sign of the second input flipped. So provided you can add with one negative number ...

Comment: @Joseph. No: when I wrote "I cannot subtract", what I actually meant is "I cannot add numbers with opposite signs. I didn't want to use tests at each step for the carry. I fixed it by pre-carrying: `\number\numexpr #1-#5-1+\expandafter\carry:w ~ ~ \number\numexpr 1#2-#6-1+\expandafter\carry:w ~ ~ \number\numexpr 1#3-#7-1+\expandafter\carry:w ~ ~ \number\numexpr 1#4-#8\relax` where each argument is 4 digits (and `~` are just for clarity here). `\carry:w` puts the last four digits in braces, leaving the carry to be added with the previous level.

Comment: @Bruno: doing numbers with different signs is done by branching, usually, with a absolute addition or difference followed by a sing tidy-up. If you can pull off the absolute sign expandably then I think you can do the absolute difference.

Comment: @Joseph: detecting the overall sign is easy, but I didn't want to have a test for each block of digits when subtracting. To go faster, I did this pre-carry that I mentionned: then all intermediate results are positive, and we just need to check the overall sign at the end. If it is negative, extra steps are needed, but if it is positive, we are done, with only one test. --- In the code for `\fp_add:NNNNNNNNN` (internal addition), you only use `\c_one_thousand_million`. But you just said you used 1+9+ _3_ digits?

Comment: @Bruno: I've only used additional internal digits for the more complex calculations such as sines. For the basic arithmetic functions it's just done with what you see (plus from memory one block as part of the multiplication, which is done 'on the fly').

Answer (score 7):

Macros cannot return values, only expand to a result.
The problem here is that assignments in TeX must be *executed* and are not *expandable*. One way to do this is to define the result in another macro which then can be expanded and is some form of indirect return value.

The `pgfmath` library of the `pgf` package does it like that. The expression is processed by `\pgfmathparse{...}` and the result is stored in `\pgfmathresult`. Alternatively `\pgfmathsetmacro\mymacro{...}` can be used.

Some notable exceptions are the eTeX primitives `\dimexpr`, `\numexpr` and `\skipexpr` which can do some arithmetic and are expandable.

Comment: A very valuable observation regarding the distinction between the two kinds of computations carried out within a macro, the first being the conversion of one set of tokens (arguments, but not only arguments) into another set of arguments, and the other, changing and communicating with the current state of the TeX machine, by defining new macros, setting values to registers and the sort. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Consider this example, using the `fp` package to perform calculations<sup>1</sup>.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
%% Calculates the area of an average person
%% given the body mass m and the height h
%% using the Du Bois equation
\def\body@area#1#2{
  \FPpow\t@one{#1}{0.425}%
  \FPpow\t@two{#2}{0.725}%
  \FPmul\t@three{\t@one}{\t@two}%
  \FPmul\A@D{0.202}{\t@three}%
  \FPmul\@watts{\A@D}{58.2}%
Your body area is \SI{\A@D}{\square\meter}   and generates \SI{\@watts}{W}%
}

\texttt{\body@area{70}{1.8} }
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

It creates the macro names on the fly and passes the values to other macros (as close as you will ever get to chaining with TeX). Each computer language affects the way you program. It is best to think in terms of TeX, similarly to learning a foreign language, where the advice is not to directly translate into your mother tongue, but think in terms of the grammar of the new language.

<sup>1</sup> Example uses the Du Bois equation to calculate the surface area and heat generated by a person based on weight and height!

Comment: Thumbs up for a very entertaining and useful example!

Comment: And, yes, the mindset is very important. What I was trying to elicit in this question is the realization in TeX's mindset of two important principles: (a) minimal coupling between the caller and callee, and (b) superimposition, or modularity, if you like. Can one understand the whole as the sum of its parts?

Comment: you can get closer to chaining, by forcing the expansion of the subexpression using `\number`. But for this, everrything needs to be expandable, which is tough, as I discovered.

Answer (score 7):

As has already been commented, TeX is a macro expansion language which means that with the exception of the primitives you don't get the behaviour of functions in many other languages. In the example cited it is possible to have the desired behaviour, at least with e-TeX, as `\numexpr` is expandable:

```
\catcode`\@=11\relax
\def\Abs#1{\number\numexpr\ifnum#1<\z@ -\fi\numexpr#1\relax}
\Abs{-4}:%
\Abs{\Abs{-3}-\Abs{2}}
\bye
```

There are also ways to get full expansion by using `\romannumeral` or `\csname` (see for example the answers to [Expandable full expansion of tokens that preserves catcodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/expandable-full-expansion-of-tokens-that-preserves-catcodes)), but ensuring that you get function-like behaviour is not always easy. There is also performance to consider, and in most cases it's best to accept that TeX is an expansion language.

Answer (score 6):

With `lualatex` it is pretty easy to define:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\abs#1{\directlua{tex.print(math.abs(#1))}}    
\begin{document}

\abs{-3.1}
\abs{3.1}
\abs{0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with lualatex, so I am not sure I got it.  How should I go about storing the result of the macro?

Comment: for example: `\def\AbsVal{\abs{-3.1}}`

Comment: That doesn't store the result, but the tokens `\abs{-3.1}`. You might prefer using an `\edef` here.

Answer (score 0):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package you can write functions in a similar way to other programming language such as `C` or `Lua`. The evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{functional}

\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \Abs {M} { 
  \IntCompareTF {#1} > {0}
    { \Result { \IntEval{#1} } }
    { \Result { \IntEval{-#1} } }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\IntSet \lTmpaInt {-1}
\IntSet \lTmpkInt {\Abs{\lTmpaInt}}
\IntUse \lTmpkInt

\IntSet \lTmpbInt {5}
\Abs {\IntMathSub {\Abs{\lTmpaInt}} {\Abs{\lTmpbInt}}}

\end{document}
```

Note that with this package, you need to pass return values of functions with `\Result` command.