# What does \@car do?

Tags: macros

The title says it all. I'd like to know what `\@car` does. I came across it reading through the source of the `hyperref` package, but it doesn't seem it's defined as part of the package. I tried Google, but there is the sub-string "car" ...

Comment: See perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/lisp-relics-in-latexe-logo and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64725/implementing-car-and-cdr-in-tex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In LISP, it returns the first element of a list or a pair. In LaTeX, its definition is `\def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}` (defined right before `\def\@cdr#1#2\@nil{#2}`), and it is defined in LaTeX core (`latex.ltx`).

The origins of the word come from the [architecture of some early IBM computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR#Etymology).