# \ifblank does not work correctly with \pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfkeys, etoolbox

The macro `\test` below is used to test if its argument is `blank`, and it gives unexpected result.

What's wrong with my code?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{aaa/.initial={}}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{#1}{blank}{#1}%
}
<\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}>% Typeset "<>"
|\test{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}|%I think it should be "|blank|", but actually it typesets "||". Why?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `\pgfkeysvalueof{<full key>}` need three expansions

According to its definition, it takes three expansions for `\pgfkeysvalueof{<full key>}` to expand to the value held in `<full key>`.

```tex
% run `latexdef -p pgfkeys -s \pgfkeysvalueof` and you'll get

% pgfkeys.code.tex, line 172:
\def\pgfkeysvalueof#1{\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname}
```

- step one, `\pgfkeysvalueof` expands to its replacement text, which is in the form of `\csname ... \endcsname`.
- step two, `\csname ... \endcsname` expands to a control sequence that holds the value of `<full key>`. For `/aaa`, it's `\pgfk@/aaa`.
- step three, that control sequence expands to its replacement text. For `/aaa`, the expansion result is empty.

The exact definition of `\pgfkeysvalueof` will change in the next release, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/pull/1132, but the number of steps will remain the same.

Therefore

```tex
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}
```

works.

#### `\pgfkeysValueOf` that takes only two steps

In general,

- case 1: if the string to be tested *is* the replacement text of a macro, then OP's `\test` works for this macro, like `\test{\cmd}`;
- case 2: if the string to be tested is the (finite steps of) *expansion of* replace text of a macro, then in theory we can define a command `\cmdExpanded`, based on `\cmd`, that only need two expansions. That means,  `\expandafter\test\expandafter{\cmdExpanded}}}` works.

The `\pgfkeysValueOf` provided in example below belongs to case 2.

In addition, if expandability is not the key point, then `pgfkeys`'s  `\pgfkeysgetvalue{<full key>}{<macro>}` is another choice, for example

```tex
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/aaa}{\temp} % here \temp belongs to case 1
|\test{\temp}|
```

#### Example, with test cases to distinguish "blank value" from "non-blank value that expands to blank":

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}

% OP's definiton
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{#1}{blank}{#1}%
}

% egreg's answer
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testExpl}{m}
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { #1 } {blank} {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% wipet's answer
\def\testExpanded#1{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}{blank}{#1}}

% joseph's answer
\newcommand{\testRomannumeral}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q#1 }{blank}{#1}%
}

% my solution 1, expand three steps 
\newcommand{\testThreeExps}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily

% three tests
\pgfkeys{
  aaa/.initial={},       % blank: empty
  bbb/.initial={{ }},    % blank: a space
  ccc/.initial={\empty}, % non-blank: expand to empty
  ddd/.initial={\space}, % non-blank: expand to a space
  eee/.initial={eee},    % non-blank: expand to non-blank
}


\leavevmode\llap{Expected}%
\foreach \j in {aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee} {%
  % use \pgfkeysgetvalue, then one step expansion
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/\j}{\temp}%
  \makebox[2cm]{|\test{\temp}|}%
}\bigskip

\foreach \i in {\test, \testExpl, \testExpanded, \testRomannumeral, \testThreeExps} {%
  \leavevmode\llap{\detokenize\expandafter{\i}}%
  \foreach \j in {aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee} {%
    \makebox[2cm]{|\i{\pgfkeysvalueof{/\j}}|}%
  }
  \par
}

% \pgfkeysValueOf{<full key>} takes one step to expansion to <full key>'s value
\newcommand{\pgfkeysValueOf}[1]{%
  \expanded{\unexpanded
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}}%
}

\leavevmode\hspace*{-4cm}%
\verb|\expandafter\test\expandafter{\pgfkeysValueOf{<full key>}}|\par%
\foreach \j in {aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee} {%
  \makebox[2cm]{|\expandafter\test\expandafter{\pgfkeysValueOf{/\j}}|}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the test cases distinguish "blank key value" from "non-blank key value that expands to blank". Values of `/aaa` and `/bbb` are both blank, but values of `/ccc` and `/ddd` are neither blank, though they both expand to blank.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! And, instead of `aaa/.initial={}`,  only define a key, not to give it a value like `aaa/.initial`, is there a better way to detect whether a key has been allocated value?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what "instead of `aaa/.initial={}`, only define a key, not to give it a value like `aaa/.initial`" mean. Also, are your keys only defined by handler `/.initial` and never by handler `/.code` and its friends?

Comment: In the form of `aaa/.initial={}`, the key "aaa" is allocated a value of empty.  In the form of `aaa/.initial`, nothing is allocated to "aaa". In this case, I guess the output of  `\pgfkeysvalueof{aaa}` will be `\relax`(or `\empty`? I'm not sure). If it's `\relax`, is there a better way to detect it?

Comment: According to how `/initial` is defined (`\pgfkeys{/handlers/.initial/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}}`, see [`pgfkeys.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/acfa21c9fb09909ce5fa8f9760f0a706e32753e5/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex#L842)) and the doc for `/.code`, the default value of `/.initial` is `\pgfkeysnovalue`, which is defined by `\def\pgfkeysnovalue{\pgfkeys@novalue}` with `\def\pgfkeys@novalue{}`. That means, `aaa/.initial` is equivalent to `aaa/.initial=\pgfkeysnovalue`.

Comment: Then, how to detect this condition(only aaa/.initial, nothing is allocated to "aaa")? I want it gives blank.

Comment: Whenever a key is defined, it _always_ stores some value, possibly empty. With `\pgfkeys{a/.initial, b/.initial=\pgfkeysnovalue, c/.initial=}`, `/a` and `/b` (internally macros `\pgfk@/a` and `\pgfk@/b`) both hold `\pgfkeysnovalue`, hence are _indistinguishable_. And `/c` holds nothing, equivalent to `\@namedef{pgfk@/c}{}`. Thus strictly speaking, you can't detect if a key `aaa` is defined by `aaa/.initial` and never used. In real life, you may assume that no one will use `aaa/.initial=\pgfkeysnovalue` and determine whether the value of key is `\pgfkeysnovalue`.

Answer (score 4):

`\pgfkeysvalueof` doesn't expand in one step, so a single `\expandafter` can't work here. You need to force expansion: probably easiest using the '[roman numeral trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/expandable-full-expansion-of-tokens-that-preserves-catcodes/7524#7524)':

```latex
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q#1 }{blank}{#1}%
}
```

Comment: How can I learn the number of steps to expand?

Comment: @lyl That depends on the implementation: in general commands don't specify how many expansions are required, hence using a 'forced' approach here. Some low-level stuff does specify expansion steps, e.g. bits of `expl3`, some of the Heiko Oberdiek bundle.

Answer (score 4):

Rommannumeral trick does full expansion until there is something unexpandable. But if the argument is in the format `bla\macro` and the `\macro` expands to `nk` then rommannumeral trick fails. So, I suggest to use `\expanded` primitive:

```
\def\test#1{\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}{blank}{#1}}
```

Comment: Thank you @wipet! And where does `\expanded` come from?

Comment: I thought about `\expanded`, but as we don't know the nature of the value to be tested, I'd avoid if possible. Also, for a blank test, it's unimportant what stops the expansion: anything which stops `\romannumeral` will count as 'not blank'

Comment: @lyl `\expanded` was originally proposed for pdfTeX 1.50 but was made public first in LuaTeX; it's been in all major engines for a few years now

Comment: Many thanks all!

Comment: Why does `\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\expanded{\ }}{blank}{not blank}` typeset `not blank`?

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-liner with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{aaa/.initial={}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { #1 } {blank} {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

<\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}>% Typeset "<>"

|\test{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}|

\pgfkeys{aaa=xyz}

<\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}>% Typeset "<>"

|\test{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\test{\ }` does not give `blank`, why?

Comment: @lyl Because it’s not blank, but contains an unexpandable primitive.

Comment: Since `\ ` outputs a white space, why is it not blank and unexpandable?

Comment: @lyl It doesn't just output a space, but also does other jobs. So it's very different from a space.

Comment: So, are there general methods to `test blank` including this case?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is to test if the key typeset to a size-0 box (this is a mixed answer with the [XY question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649265/how-to-extract-text-from-argument)).

But notice that an explicit space is not the same thing as a blank content...

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%<- you forgot this!
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\newsavebox{\measbox}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
    \savebox{\measbox}{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd\measbox>0pt \usebox\measbox \else blank\fi
}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{aaa/.initial={}}
<\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}>% Typesets "<>" (with the T1 fontenc, otherwise ¡?)

|\test{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}|% typesets |blank|

\pgfkeys{aaa=\bfseries}

|\test{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}|% typesets |blank|

\pgfkeys{aaa=~}

|\test{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}|% typesets | |

\pgfkeys{aaa=\bfseries ~}

|\test{\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}}|% typesets | | but slightly wider
\end{document}
```

[image: output from the snippet above]

Comment: Many thanks for this idea!! Then how to refer `explicit space` as blank? I mean the input of  `white space(s} ` will also get the typeset `blank`.

Comment: I do not know if it's really possible. TeX sees any typesettable box as a bunch of character boxes; the fact that there is something printed in them depend on the font (and TeX does not know; for what he knows, `~` can be a blank or not --- and sometimes it is not, really, like when you activate visible spaces in `tt` fonts). But you can try asking another question (you can use my snippet above for the question if you want, no problem, just cite it correctly)